# Sum of a field when all other fields are the same

Tags: crystal-reports

Here is what my data looks like

```
Name    Profession  City    Amount
Steve   Student  Vancouver  1000
Steve   Student  Vancouver  1500
Steve   Student  Vancouver  500
Ryan    Sales    Vancouver  900
Ryan    Sales    Vancouver  700
```

What I need it to look like:

After

```
Name    Profession  City    Amount  
Steve   Student Vancouver   3000
Ryan    Sales   Vancouver   1600
```

How would I go about doing this?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

- Insert group based on `Name`
- Drag `Profession` and `City` from the Detail section into the group you just created
- Right-click on `Amount` and select 'Insert > Summary'
- Change 'Summary location' to the group you created above, and press 'Okay'
- Drag the sum of amount to the group header (instead of the footer)
- Suppress the 'Details' section (and the 'Group footer' if you wish)